# How to have tabBarController automatically load the secondViewController whenever it is loaded

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

So I have a `UITabBarController` with 4 items(ViewController), and I want it to load the second ViewController every time the MainTabBarController is loaded. Is there any other way to make this happen?

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController = self.tabBarItem.homeMapViewController
```

doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass the `UITabBarController` and set this inside  `viewDidLoad`

```
self.selectedIndex = 1
```

//

```
class CustomTabBar:UITabBarController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    /// ......
    self.selectedIndex = 1
  }
}
```

and assign `CustomTabBar` to the class of the Tabbar in IB

Comment: I simply copied awakeFromNib in my UITabBarController, and it crash

Comment: use only **selectedIndex** don't write your line that's in the question

Comment: I did comment it out

Comment: you create them programmatically , so add the selectedIndex line as the last line inside  **viewDidLoad**